# "I am only me" vs. "I am only I"

Tags: word-usage, subjects, grammatical-case

Is it more correct to say "I am only me" or "I am only I?" I know that the subject should follow a linking verb like "am" or "is", *e.g.:* "It is I", but "It is me" is also correct by common educated usage. So this matter of "I am me" or "I am I" is confusing. Which is more correct?

Comment: 'I know that the subject[ive?] should follow a linking verb like "am" or "is", e.g.: "It is I" ' is perpetuating a shibboleth. This has been covered on ELU before.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when you are referring back to yourself as a subject, it were better to use "myself" instead of "I" or "me": `I am only myself, a mere mortal.`

To give an example of why "me" is better not to use, consider that "I" is to "We" as "me" is to "us". To say `I am me today` is like saying `We are us today` or `They are them today`. It were clearly better to say `I am myself today`, `We are ourselves today`, and `They are themselves today`.

Comment: It *were* better??

Comment: *Were* here is used in the subjunctive mood. If you have not heard of subjunctive, I recommend you read up on it. Many modern users of English have lost awareness of this versatile mood.

Comment: @Michael I don't think it is an issue of the subjunctive mood. You could use ***would be*** or (less likely) ***could be*** instead of ***were***. Don't you agree?

Comment: Subjunctive is not a required tool. Like many facilities in language, there are alternatives. In many cases, "would" or "could" can be used in the place of subjunctive, as you have suggested. I like using subjunctive in certain cases since it keeps the language concise and clear. I guess you could call me old-fashioned.

Comment: I am not interesting in calling you anything. I just wanted to suggest alternatives for ***were***.

Comment: I've heard of subjunctive. I use it routinely in my speech and were the opportunity to arise I'd *never ever* say, "It were better to ...".

Comment: @Jim -- To each his own when it comes to style.

Comment: You need to read what Geoff Pullum has to say about the choice of archaic forms.